# Creating a new array [] in json and pushing data using js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

needed some help, so I have a json in this format

```json
{
    "objs": {
        "block": [
            {"long": "value1"}
        ],
        "block1": [
            {"long": "value2"}
        ],
        "nameofblock": [
            {"long": "thisisthevalueoflonginjson"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I need to add a new array using js, I am not allowed to change the structure of the JSON
so now, in my js I have something like this

```js
let myBlock = "name_of_block";
let longData = "data_inside_the_block";
```

Now using these variables a new block needs to be created in the existing JS file using the variables in JS

so once these are added the JSON must look something like this

```json
{
    "objs": {
        "block": [
            {"long": "value1"}
        ],
        "block1": [
            {"long": "value2"}
        ],
        "nameofblock": [
            {"long": "thisisthevalueoflonginjson"}
        ],
        "name_of_block": [
            {"long": "data_inside_the_block"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading! I have tried in Discord, but still couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as this should do the trick:

```js
myJSON.objs[myBlock] = [{"long": longData}];
```

Where `myJSON` is the object you want to attach it to.

See the example below:

```js
const myJSON = {
    "objs": {
        "block": [
            {"long": "value1"}
        ],
        "block1": [
            {"long": "value2"}
        ],
        "nameofblock": [
            {"long": "thisisthevalueoflonginjson"}
        ]
    }
};

let myBlock = "name_of_block";
let longData = "data_inside_the_block";

myJSON.objs[myBlock] = [{"long": longData}];

console.log(myJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON structure is same with JS Object.

so you can do it like below.

```
function createBlock = (longData) => [{"long":longData}];
jsonObj.objs[myBlock] = createBlock(longData);
```